# I am held up with an Error "Webpage is blocked "while opening vcenter

Tags: privacy, vcenter, blocked

Team,
Whenever i open the vcenter and i can see the Error" Webpage is blocked" & "You have tried to access a web page which belongs to a category that is blocked".

Can anybody helps to sort out this issue ?

Note :- There is no issue in the Firewall as well, i can recieve the response from the server.

I am expecting for solution.